# Figuring out the pseudo code to hangman C++

Tags: c++, do-loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
bool guessedWord;
bool wantsToPlay;
char answer;
int errorCount = 0;
char userGuess;

char letter1 = '_', letter2 = '_', letter3 = '_', letter4 = '_', letter5 = '_', letter6 = '_';  // Letters to store and display the hidden characters
string hiddenWord = "BASICS";
string availableLetters = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"; // Alphabet
string gallow1 = "     |------|--";     // Gallows to display hangman image
string gallow2 = "     |      ";
string gallow3 = "     |      ";
string gallow4 = "     |     ";
string gallow5 = "     |    ";
string gallow6 = "   ====== ";



cout << endl;   // START TURN
cout << endl;

cout << gallow1 << endl;    // Gallows Display
cout << gallow2 << endl;
cout << gallow3 << endl;
cout << gallow4 << endl;
cout << gallow5 << endl;
cout << gallow6 << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;

// Display hidden letters and alphabet
cout << letter1 << " " << letter2 << " " << letter3 << " " << letter4 << " " << letter5 << " " << letter6 << " " << endl << endl;
cout << availableLetters << endl << endl;

cout << "Please enter your letter choice >>";
cin >> userGuess;
userGuess = toupper(userGuess);

do  //plays a new game
{
    do //play specific game
    {
                                            //Change guessed word or add error count,
                                        

        if (userGuess == hiddenWord[0]) // checking for a match
        {
            letter1 = userGuess;                
            availableLetters[2] = '_';
        }
        else if (userGuess == hiddenWord[1])
        {
            letter2 = userGuess;
            availableLetters[0] = '_';
        }
        else if (userGuess == hiddenWord[2])
        {
            letter3 = userGuess;
            letter6 = userGuess;
            availableLetters[36] = '_';
        }
        else if (userGuess == hiddenWord[3])
        {
            letter4 = userGuess;
            availableLetters[16] = '_';
        }
        else if (userGuess == hiddenWord[4])
        {
            letter5 = userGuess;
            availableLetters[4] = '_';
        }
        else
        {
            errorCount++;
            if (errorCount == 1)
                gallow2 += "O";         //Add a head
            else if (errorCount == 2)
                gallow3 += "|";         //Add a body
            else if (errorCount == 3)
                gallow3.at(11) = '/';   //Add a right arm
            else if (errorCount == 4)
                gallow3 += "\\";        //Add a left arm
            else if (errorCount == 5)
                gallow4 += "/";         //Add a right leg
            else if (errorCount == 6)
        }
        
    } while (guessedWord == false || errorCount < 6);
    
    if (guessedWord == true)
    {
        cout << "YAY!!!! YOU WIN" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You are dead" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Do you want to play again?" << endl;
    cout << "Y / N" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 'N')
        wantsToPlay = false;
} while (wantsToPlay == true);
cout << "BYE" << endl;


cout << "GAME OVER....\n\n";

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

This is the code I have been trying to run with the hanman project but it seems some problems are there I can't figure them out as I am very much new to programming. It would help if someone could point them out. I also have the pseudo code which our professor gave and can't figure out what to do with it. The error is showing that I have an guessedWord is uninitialised and I don;t know what it means. Hope someone can help me figure this out as soon as possible.

Comment: it would be best to ask the professor for help. we can't do your home assignment for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, did you try to compile your program with all warnings enabled?

The compiler will tell you what is wrong and what needs to be fixed.

After removing the hard bugs, like missing braces, I received the below messages:
[image]

A big problem are your not initialized variables. There values are indeterminate.

How should `} while (guessedWord == false || errorCount < 6);` work, if the variable "guessedWord " has never been initialized?

So, please always initialize all your variables. Always.

Then run your compiler with all warnings enabled and fix all messages.

Then, we can talk again.